# Fatal：Unable to attach to remote geth :dial unix /home/user/eth_data_para0/data13/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory

Tags: ethereum

When I run a code within geth command, sometimes it goes well, but sometimes it gave me these errors:

1. Fatal：Unable to attach to remote geth :dial unix /home/user/eth_data_para0/data13/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory

2.Fatal：Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /home/user/eth_data_para0/data11/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Comment: was wondering if it's just the problem about the ports which are not open?